adding mysql dependency to my springboot project
so i have been trying to add a dependency of "mysql" to the pom.xml but it keeps giving me errors i have mysql version 8.0.36 installed,what should i do?
           " <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.36</version>
    </dependency>"

that is how i have added it any help will be appreciated
i tried to change how to add it by using com.mysql forexample but still , am expecting the dependency to be added

What is the exact error message you are getting?
